# Creating User Session in MonoDroid

Tags: android, session, xamarin.android

I am developing and android application which required user to login. I am using Monodroid to develop this application. In my application there are bunch of activities that will be started as the user logs in. I have set up Login Activity as main launcher and when user is successfully logged in , user will be sent to main activity.

I some how want to save session for the user so that user do not need to login every time they start the application.

As monodroid is very new to me, i am not able to make that work. People recommended me using SharedPrefrencs to create session, but tried lot to make it work, application always crashed. 
The reason for crashing is null value of user, when user is in mainactivity. As recommended by many users i create Main Activity as main laucher and check if user is logged in or not from there. But nothing worked for me.

I have included my whole code for Login Activity and Main Activity. I want to save "driverId" in prefrences and when ever app is relauched main activity will retrieve "driverId" from the prefrences.

Please some body who is familiar with monodroid enviroment can help me to fix this.

**Login Activity Code**

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Locations;
using RestSharp;
using TheNorthStar.Api.Requests;
using TheNorthStar.Api.Results;
using NorthStar.Driver.Application;
using Android.Preferences;
using Object = Java.Lang.Object;


namespace NorthStar.Driver
{
    public class DriverLogonAsync : AsyncTask

    {
        private ProgressDialog processDialog;
        private Context m_context;
        private DriverLogon m_driver;

        private bool _resterror;

        public DriverLogonAsync( Context context, DriverLogon driver )
        {
            m_context = context;
            m_driver = driver;

            _resterror = false;
        }

        /*
         * throws
         * should separate out logic and use MyMessagebox..
         */
        private void SetComfirmAlertBox(string carNum, DriverLogonResult result)
        {
            var api = new ConnectToSever(Helper.GetServer(m_context));
            string resultOfCarDetail; CarDetails res;
            try
            {
                resultOfCarDetail = api.ComfirmLogginOn(m_driver);
            }
            catch
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_conflogon1", "confirm logging on failed");
                throw;
            }
            try
            {
                res = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarDetails>(resultOfCarDetail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_conflogon2", "deserialize confirm logging on failed\n" + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }

            if (res.carExists != true)
            {
                MyMessageBox.SetAlertBox("Opps!!!!!!!!", "This Car Number Was Wrong!!!!", "OK", m_context);
            }
            else
            {
                string carType = res.carType;
                string seatNum = res.numOfSeats.ToString();
               // MainActivity act = new MainActivity( result.driverId );
                var mact = new Intent(m_context,typeof(MainActivity) );
                mact.PutExtra( "driverID",  result.driverId.ToString() );
                MyMessageBox.SetAlertBox("Comfirm!", "Your car is a: " + carType + " with " + seatNum + " seats??", "Yes", "No", mact,m_context);


            }
        }

        /*private void ChangeDriverStatues()
        {

        }*/

        protected override void OnPreExecute()
        {
            base.OnPreExecute();
            processDialog = ProgressDialog.Show( m_context, "Driver Loging On...", "Please Wait...", true, true);
        }



        protected override Object DoInBackground(params Object[] @params)
        {
            var api = new ConnectToSever(Helper.GetServer(m_context));

            string res = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                res = api.DriverLogingOn(m_driver);
            }
            catch
            {
                _resterror = true;
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_dlogon1", "driver logon failed");
                return -1;
            }
            return res;
        }

        protected override void OnPostExecute(Object result)
        {
            base.OnPostExecute(result);
            //hide and kill the progress dialog
            processDialog.Hide();
            processDialog.Cancel();

            if (_resterror == true)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_dlogon2", "logon connection has failed, noop");
                return;
            }

            DriverLogonResult resDriverDetail;
            try
            {
                resDriverDetail = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DriverLogonResult>(result.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_dlogon3", "logon deser has failed, noop\n" + ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            if (resDriverDetail.logonSuccess)
            {
                this.SetComfirmAlertBox( m_driver.carNum, resDriverDetail );  
            }
            else
            {
                MyMessageBox.SetAlertBox("Wrong!", "Wrong username or password!!!", "OK!",m_context);
            }
        }
    }

    [Activity(Label = "MyDriver-Driver", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", NoHistory = true)]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        private void CreateAlert()
        {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.SetTitle("GPS is Off")
                .SetMessage("You need GPS to you this application."+ "\n" +
                             "Do you want to go to settings menu?")
                .SetPositiveButton("Setting",
                    (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
                        StartActivity(intent);
                        this.Finish();
                    })
                    .SetNegativeButton("No", (sender, e) => this.Finish());

            AlertDialog alert = builder.Create();
            alert.Show();
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_logstart", "**************** starting driver module ****************");

            Boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
            Boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
            LocationManager _locationManager;
            _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
            isGPSEnabled = _locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = _locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NetworkProvider);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                CreateAlert();
            }

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            EditText eTextUsername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.UserNameBox);
            EditText eTextPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.PasswordBox);
            EditText eTextCarNum = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.CarNumBox);
            Button viewPrefsBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnViewPrefs);
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate 
            {
                if (eTextCarNum.Text != "" && eTextPassword.Text != "" && eTextUsername.Text != "")
                {
                    DriverLogon driver = new DriverLogon();
                    driver.userName = eTextUsername.Text;
                    driver.password = eTextPassword.Text;
                    driver.carNum = eTextCarNum.Text;
                    DriverLogonAsync asyDriver = new DriverLogonAsync(this, driver);
                    asyDriver.Execute();
                }
            };

            viewPrefsBtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(PreferencesActivity));
            };
        }
    }
}
```

So when user is successfully logged in "driverId" should be saved and can be retrived from main activity when re launching app.

**Main Activity Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Android.Preferences;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using RestSharp;
using Android.Locations;
using TheNorthStar.Api.Requests;
using TheNorthStar.Api.Results;
using NorthStar.Driver.Application;
using System.Timers;
using AutoMapper;
using Object = Java.Lang.Object;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;


namespace NorthStar.Driver
{
    [Activity(Label = "Home")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {   
        string m_driverId;
        string m_bookingId;
        string m_address;
        int i = 1;
        private Timer _requestWorkTimer;

        /*
         * throws
         */
        private void SetDriverStatues(string status)
        {
            m_driverId = Intent.GetStringExtra("driverID");
            var api = new ConnectToSever(Helper.GetServer(ApplicationContext));
            DriverLogon driver = new DriverLogon();
            //Booking booking = RequestToSever();
            driver.driverID = Int32.Parse(m_driverId);
            driver.driverStatus = status;
            try
            {
                api.SetDriverStatus(driver);
            }
            catch
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_setdstat1", "set driver status failed");
                throw;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            _requestWorkTimer.Stop();
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Mainpage);
            //EditText messageBox = FindViewById<EditText>( Resource.Id.MessagesBox );
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.LogOutButton);

            m_driverId = Intent.GetStringExtra("driverID");
            var service = new Intent(this, typeof(NorthStarBackgroundService));
            service.PutExtra("driverId",m_driverId);

            StartService(service);


            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => SetDriverStatues("Available"));
           // this.SetDriverStatues( "Available" );

            _requestWorkTimer = new Timer(15000);
            _requestWorkTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => RequestWork());
            };
            _requestWorkTimer.Start();

            button.Click += (sender, args) =>
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        SetDriverStatues("Logoff");
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_setdstat2", "set driver status failed");
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    var mact = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
                                    mact.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                                    StartActivity(mact);
                                };
        }

        private void CheckMessage()
        {
          /*  if (  )
            {
                //timeout so return home

            }
           /* else
            {
                timerCount--;
                RunOnUiThread(() => { jobTimerLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} seconds to respond", timerCount); });

            }*/
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            _requestWorkTimer.Start();
        }

        private void CreateAlert()
        {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.SetTitle("GPS is Off")
                .SetMessage("Do you want to go to settings menu?")
                .SetPositiveButton("Setting",
                    (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
                        StartActivity(intent);
                        this.Finish();
                    })
                    .SetNegativeButton("No", (sender, e) => this.Finish());

            AlertDialog alert = builder.Create();
            alert.Show();
        }

        /*
         * throws
         */
        private void RequestWork()
        {
            _requestWorkTimer.Stop();
            var api = new ConnectToSever(Helper.GetServer(ApplicationContext));
            DriverMoreWorkRequest driver = new DriverMoreWorkRequest();
            driver.driverID = Int32.Parse(m_driverId);
            NorthStarBackgroundService n = new NorthStarBackgroundService();
            driver.Lat = n.currentLattitude;
            driver.Lng = n.currentLongtitude;
            Object result; Booking booking;
            try
            {
                result = api.RequestWork(driver);
            }
            catch
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_reqwork1", "request work failed");
                throw;
            }
            try
            {
                booking = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Booking>(result.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_reqwork1", "deserialize request work failed\n" + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
            if (booking != null)
            {
                m_bookingId = booking.BookingId.ToString();
                //string add = api.GetCustomerAddress(booking);

                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    var mact = new Intent(this, typeof(NewWorkAvailableActivity));
                    mact.PutExtra("driverID", m_driverId);
                    mact.PutExtra("bookingId", m_bookingId);
                    mact.PutExtra("fullAddress", booking.Address);
                    mact.PutExtra("jobLocation", booking.PickupSuburb);
                    mact.PutExtra("customerPhoneNumber", booking.PassengerPhoneNumber);

                    StartActivity(mact);

                });
            }
            else
            {
                _requestWorkTimer.Start();
            }                     
        }

        public object even { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm exactly sure what you are trying to do here but to get driver ID from Shared Preferences try (from the login activity):

```
var prefs = GetSharedPreferences("MyApp",Android.Content.FileCreationMode.Private);
var driverID = 0;
if (prefs.Contains("DriverID"))
{
    driverID = prefs.GetInt("DriverID", 0);
}
else
{
    //Call the Async Task to get the Driver or whatever and when you've got it:
    var prefsEdit = prefs.Edit();
    prefsEdit.PutInt("DriverID", driver.ID);
    prefsEdit.Commit();
    driverID = prefs.GetInt("DriverID", 0);
}

var mact = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity))
            .PutExtra("driverID", driverID);
StartActivity(mact);
```

Alternatively I would stick the whole Driver object in a sqlite db and get it back every time you come in but obviously I don't know your requirements.

Comment: I am ready to post whole solution if you can help me with it. I am not sure how to implement you above mention code.

Comment: @Armit Sharma - I don't think you need to post your whole solution.  Which bit of the code are you struggling with?  Check out [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for more info on storage options in Android.  Most of the Java can fairly easily be translated to C#.